# Train and Export Model from Kfold Cross Validation with scikit learn and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, export, cross-validation, training-data

I have a small data set and therefore want to use cross-validation to achieve a higher accuracy of results. 
I use a canned tf.estimator (tf.estimator.DNN regressor).

My question is now:
If I have the model trained for each split from Kfold, do I have to use "shutil.rmtree(model_dir, ignore_errors=True)" every time to reset the training success or it will be done automatically with every train command.
If I reset it now, how can I export the optimal model from all splits afterwards?
Or do I not have to reset train at all but just keep on training with a new data set from the splits.

Comment: Hi Davingun, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question might be better placed at CrossValidated.